# Where does apache store the location of php?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I have compiled PHP 5.3 on ubuntu about two months ago following Brandon Savages guide (I think). It works. Now I wanted to see in what file apache stored the location of the PHP binary but I can't find it, it's not in any configuration file. Does apxs2 has something to do with that?

edit:

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

gives

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

Comment: Thanks. The output: "LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so"

I've seen this but couldn't connect it to a php binary. How does this file load PHP?

Comment: Is this file created and added to the apache dir by the make/make install?

Comment: When PHP is built/used as a module the PHP interpreter is loaded into the Apache server (via that LoadModule directive).  The web server and the PHP interpreter run in the same process - think Kirby eating critters and gaining their powers :)